# Confusion with potential difference

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, potential, electrical-resistance, voltage

I was trying to solve a hard problem involving a circuit like this:

Find the reading on the voltmeter (red ones are resistors)

[image]

I don't know how to think about potential difference across branches like this. I mean what is the voltmeter measuring the potential across? In general I'm just looking for some intuition that can help me think about potential difference better for problems like this, because I am only experienced in simple ones where you measure potential directly across a component.

Thanks

Potential diagram:

[image]

[image]

Front view of stairs:

[image]

Comment: That's not necessarily simpler.  (Ideal) voltmeters are not part of a circuit and have no current flow.  In the top diagram, no current crosses the legs of the voltmeter.  In the bottom circuit, there is no path for current to avoid the voltmeter.  This makes the problem much different.

Comment: @BowlOfRed: Thanks, maybe i should leave the original problem.

Comment: @BowlOfRed: I have edited. Would really appreciate if you can answer, thanks!

Comment: Do you understand how to calculate current flow and voltage drop across resistors?  If the two legs of the circuit were separated, could you find those values for each?

Comment: @BowlOfRed: Yes, I understand how to do those.

Comment: There's a good question in here somewhere but those 3D diagrams are really distracting and not helpful. Can you tighten up the question?

Answer (score 1):

What the voltmeter is reading in the top circuit would be, if you used a Kirchhoff's loop rule in the loop containing 2 resistors and the voltmeter, the difference in the potential difference across the top-right resistor and the bottom-right resistor. The loop rule calculation would look something like this ($A,B,C,\&D$ are the top-left, top-right, bottom-left, and bottom-right resistors respectively):
$$ - V_B + V + V_D = 0.$$
So once you've figured out the current in the two branches, you can find V across the resistors $B$ and $D$, using Ohm's Law, and the difference, $V_D - V_B$ will give you the potential difference across the voltmeter. You may have to switch the signs depending on the actual values and which potential is higher.